# VB net. Morse code translator: cut correct signs using Mid() and match them with the letter

Tags: vb.net, function, select-case

I am trying to translate Morse code into text in VB.net.
Using below code, some of the letters in the text stays untranslated. I believe the problem is with "oddel" which should indicated how many letters should be cut in Mid(morsC, i, oddel), while selecting the case.
Code should be able to translate this >…./ ./ .-../ .-../ ---/< into Hello.

What's weird is that while translating "Hello", first letter "H" is correctly cut as " ..../" but it's not matched with the Case "H"

```
'Hello = …./ ./ .-../ .-../ ---/
Sub EE15a()
    Dim veta As String, morsCod As String, st As String
    morsCod = InputBox("Enter the morse code.")
    veta = morsCodF(morsCod)
    st = "Preklad dle funkce " + Chr(10) + veta + Chr(10)
    MsgBox(st)
End Sub
Function morsCodF(morsC As String) As String
    Dim pismeno As String, znak As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, oddel As Integer
    Dim nasel As Boolean
    znak = "/"
    morsC = Trim(morsC)
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To (morsC.Length)
        i = j
        Do
            If Mid(morsC, j, 1) = znak Then
                oddel = j - oddel
                nasel = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop Until nasel = True Or j > (morsC.Length)
        If i = 1 Then
            pismeno = (" " + Mid(morsC, i, oddel))
        Else
            pismeno = Mid(morsC, i, oddel)
        End If
        Select Case pismeno '" ...-/"
            Case " .-/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " a"
            Case " -.../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " b"
            Case " -.-./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " c"
            Case " -../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " d"
            Case " ./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " e"
            Case " ..-./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " f"
            Case " --./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " g"
            Case " ..../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " h"
            Case " ../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " i"
            Case " .---/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " j"
            Case " -.-/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " k"
            Case " .-../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " l"
            Case " --/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " m"
            Case " -./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " n"
            Case " ---/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " o"
            Case " .--./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " p"
            Case " --.-/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " q"
            Case " .-./" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " r"
            Case " .../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " s"
            Case " -/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " t"
            Case " ..-/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " u"
            Case " ...-/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " v"
            Case " .--/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " w"
            Case " -..-/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " x"
            Case " -.--/" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " y"
            Case " --../" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " z"
            Case "#" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " "
        End Select
        nasel = False
        pismeno = ""
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Function
```

Code should translate whole word or sentence, but instead is translating only part of the text. E.g. > …./ ./ .-../ .-../ ---/
expected: "Hello", actual: "e o"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the string morsCod with "/" as separator

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub EE15a()
        Dim veta As String, morsCod As String, st As String
        'morsCod = InputBox("Enter the morse code.")
        morsCod = "..../ ./ .-../ .-../ ---/ --"
        morsCod = " .-/ -.../ -.-./ -../ ./ ..-./ --./ ..../ ../ .---/ -.-/ .-../ --/ -./ ---/ .--./ --.-/ .-./ .../ -/ ..-/ ...-/ .--/ -..-/ -.--/ --.."
        veta = morsCodF(morsCod)
        st = "Preklad dle funkce " + Chr(10) + veta + Chr(10)
        MsgBox(st)
    End Sub
    Function morsCodF(morsC As String) As String
        Dim arr As String() = morsC.Split("/"c)
        For Each s As String In arr
            Select Case s
                Case " .-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " a"
                Case " -..." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " b"
                Case " -.-." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " c"
                Case " -.." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " d"
                Case " ." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " e"
                Case " ..-." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " f"
                Case " --." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " g"
                Case " ...." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " h"
                Case " .." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " i"
                Case " .---" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " j"
                Case " -.-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " k"
                Case " .-.." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " l"
                Case " --" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " m"
                Case " -." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " n"
                Case " ---" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " o"
                Case " .--." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " p"
                Case " --.-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " q"
                Case " .-." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " r"
                Case " ..." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " s"
                Case " -" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " t"
                Case " ..-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " u"
                Case " ...-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " v"
                Case " .--" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " w"
                Case " -..-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " x"
                Case " -.--" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " y"
                Case " --.." : morsCodF = morsCodF + " z"
                Case "#" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " "
            End Select
        Next
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        EE15a()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need some letters uppercase, you need provide additional logic (for instance, first letter is always uppercase). The following code creates dictionary with codes and their letters, parses Morse code string with Regex, extracting codes one-by-one and fetching letters based on these codes. I have created two versions - with `Regex` and `Split`.

```
Dim morse = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
{
    {".-", "a"},
    {"-...", "b"},
    {"-.-.", "c"},
    {".", "e"},
    {"....", "h"},
    {".-..", "l"},
    {"---", "o"},
    {"#", " "}
}

Dim s = "..../ ./ .-../ .-../ ---/"

'// 1. REGEX
'// Search for '.', '-' and '#' in any combinations followed by '/'
Dim mc = Regex.Matches(s, "[\.\-#]+(?=/)")
'// Fetch each code from dictionary and concatenate them
Dim x = String.Join("", mc.Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(m) morse(m.Value)))

'// 2. SPLIT
'// Dim x = String.Join("", s.Split({"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
'//                           Select(Function(z) morse(z.Replace("/", "").Trim())))

Console.WriteLine(x)

'// Output: hello
```

Comment: This is another approach, but why OP's code not working?

Comment: And you can do it with dictionary(`morse`) without "Regex magic": `text.Split("/ ").Select(Function(c) morse[c]).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), Function(b, c) b.Append(c)).ToString()`

Comment: @Fabio Actually, I *do* have version with Split - don't you see it?

Comment: Nice, yes you do. I never read comments, because they never tell truth ;)

Comment: @Fabio Actually, there's a code and *even* mentioning about *two* versions in answer's text itself!  Happy New Year! 

Comment: And still lacking of the reason why OP's code not working? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get more feedback of the code if you add default case for the `Select Case` switch.

```
Select Case s
    Case " .-" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " a"
    Case "#" : morsCodF = morsCodF + " "
    Case Else : morsCodF = morsCodF + " WRONG! "
End Select
```

1. Check does this line `oddel = j - oddel` works as expected.
   Based on the logic you have `oddel` should be amount of characters after previously found `/` character. If so, then calculation `oddel = j - oddel` doesn't look right.
   Because you updating `i` with current `j` calculation should be `oddel = j - (i -1)`
2. Check `For` loop.
   Because `i` updated every time with current value of `j`, code will make one extra loop which will produce "wrong" value.
3. Other suggestions.
   Decoding morse code to the text is simple mapping from one string to another.
   In vb.net `Dictionary(Of String, String)` could be good tool for this.

Do you really need `/` character? Instead you can use simple space as letter delimeter.

```
Function FromMorse(code As String) As String
    Const DELIMETER As Char = " "c
    Static Secret As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
    {
        {".-", "a"},
        {"-...", "b"},
        {"-.-.", "c"},
        {"-..", "d"},
        {".", "e"},
        {"..-.", "f"},
        {"--.", "g"},
        {"....", "h"},
        {"..", "i"},
        {".---", "j"},
        {"-.-", "k"},
        {".-..", "l"},
        {"--", "m"},
        {"-.", "n"},
        {"---", "o"},
        {".--.", "p"},
        {"--.-", "q"},
        {".-.", "r"},
        {"...", "s"},
        {"-", "t"},
        {"..-", "u"},
        {"...-", "v"},
        {".--", "w"},
        {"-..-", "x"},
        {"-.--", "y"},
        {"--..", "z"},
        {"#", " "}
    }

    Return code.Split(DELIMETER).
                Select(Function(c) Secret(c)).
                Aggregate(New StringBuilder(), Function(b, c) b.Append(c)).
                ToString()
End Function
```

Usage

```
Dim code = ".... . .-.. .-.. --- # .-- --- .-. .-.. -.."
Dim decoded = FromMorse(code)

Console.WriteLine(decoded) ' => "hello world"
```

Comment: Glad you will never read this but your version using the space as delimiter is much harder to read. The slash is better for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary for fast look-up, String.Split for brevity and a StringBuilder to keep from creating new strings on every iteration.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim s As String = GetTextFromMorse("..../ ./ .-../ .-../ ---/")
        Debug.Print(s)
 End Sub

 Private DictCode As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
    {
        {".-", "a"},
        {"-...", "b"},
        {"-.-.", "c"},
        {"-..", "d"},
        {".", "e"},
        {"..-.", "f"},
        {"--.", "g"},
        {"....", "h"},
        {"..", "i"},
        {".---", "j"},
        {"-.-", "k"},
        {".-..", "l"},
        {"--", "m"},
        {"-.", "n"},
        {"---", "o"},
        {".--.", "p"},
        {"--.-", "q"},
        {".-.", "r"},
        {"...", "s"},
        {"-", "t"},
        {"..-", "u"},
        {"...-", "v"},
        {".--", "w"},
        {"-..-", "x"},
        {"-.--", "y"},
        {"--..", "z"},
        {"#", " "}
    }

Private Function GetTextFromMorse(input As String) As String
    Dim strArray() As String = input.Split({"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each s In strArray
        sb.Append(DictCode(s.Trim))
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: Nice copy-paste ;)